# Ruby on Rails routing to incorrect action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby and I'm running into a few issues building my first solo project after following a tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am trying to create a link to my storevalue view on the welcome page like this:

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<%= link_to 'form page', controller: 'storevalue' %>
```

that is throwing this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"storevalue_path"}
```

Why is ruby trying the action index? Do I need to fix my routes.rb to reference storevalue/new which exists rather then storevalue/index (which is what it seems to be trying to reference)? If so, how do I do this, since I can't create two root in routes (according to another error message)

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/index'
root 'welcome#index'

get 'storevalue/new'
resource :storevalue
end
```

Comment: run `rake routes` on your terminal and paste the result in you question. Also show your controller code

Comment: you need a file `app/controllers/storevalue_controller.rb`, and `class StoreValueController < ApplicationController` inside that file, do you have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to go to the create storevalue form.

Your code should be

```
<%= link_to 'form page', controller: 'storevalue', action: 'new' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the action, rails assumes that it needs to find an 'index' action in the 'storevalue_path' controller.

Potential solutions :

1. Add index action in the specific controller
2. Specify `action:=>"index"` in your link_to element code

Hope this helps.